# Store a class module as a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, events

I wrote some code in a `class module` and `userform_initialize_event`. All are okay. But when I Dim the new class module and applies in the initialize event it says that variable not defined. Here is my code -

```
Dim Buttons() As New BtnClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ButtonCount As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    '   Create the Button objects
    ButtonCount = 0
    
    For Each ctl In fmHover.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ButtonCount)
            Set Buttons(ButtonCount).ButtonGroup = ctl
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

If I Dim the Buttons inside the event it does not throws any error and the code also don't works. I searched in a lot of place. Every one Dim the new class before the Initialize event. So, why my one doesn't work? Kindly suggest where is my mistake.

Here is my class module code -

```
Public WithEvents ButtonGroup As MSForms.Label

Private Sub ButtonGroup_Click()
    Msg = "You clicked " & ButtonGroup.Name
    MsgBox Msg
    ButtonGroup.Name
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong by just looking at the code you provided. Could you share the file?

Comment: First guess: `ButtonGroup` within `BtnClass` is not public.

Comment: @ENIAC of course. Here is the file link - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tes37auuuidu6p878uydy/PROJECT-BANGLA-KEYBOARD.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=lk56qqg3luhk6mhbcm2rqrcpo)

Comment: @FunThomas ButtonGroup is public. Here is the class Module code - `Public WithEvents ButtonGroup As MSForms.Label

Private Sub ButtonGroup_Click()
    Msg = "You clicked " & ButtonGroup.Name
    MsgBox Msg
    ButtonGroup.Name
End Sub`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's nearly unreadable. You can edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @FunThomas ok. Edited the question with the code. Or you can check the file from the link I have given in the comment.

Comment: a) The last `ButtonGroup.Name` makes no sense and causes a runtime. b) Instead of `fmHover`, use `Me`: `For Each ctl In Me.Controls`.

Comment: @FunThomas Is this your solution brother?

Answer (score 0):

Each label on your form should have it's own instance of the class.  The form needs a way to remember each instance - stored in a collection at the form level.

Not sure what the `ButtonCount` is doing, so have removed it.

Your form code:

```
Option Explicit '!!!Add option explicit to the top of each module!!!
                'It helps avoid so many errors that I don't think three
                'exclamations marks is enough!!!!
                '>Tools>Options>tick Require variable declaration
                '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

'Each instance of the class is stored here.
Private colLabels As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim BtnEvents As BtnClass
    
    'Initialise the collection to hold the class instances.
    Set colLabels = New Collection
    Dim ctrl As Control
    
    For Each ctrl In Me.fmHover.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            Set BtnEvents = New BtnClass 'New instance of the class.
            Set BtnEvents.AssignButton = ctrl 'Assign the label to it.
            colLabels.Add BtnEvents 'Add it to the collection so it's remembered.
        End If
    Next ctrl
    
End Sub
```

Your class module will look like:

```
Option Explicit  'More exclamation marks!!!!!!!!!

Public WithEvents ButtonGroup As MSForms.Label

'Let the class know what control it's assigned to.
Public Property Set AssignButton(ctrl As Control)
    Set ButtonGroup = ctrl
End Property

Private Sub ButtonGroup_Click()
    Dim Msg As String
    Msg = "You clicked " & ButtonGroup.Name
    MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Comment: It is also throwing error. `variable not defined` in the `Set colLabels = New Collection` line.

Comment: Have you got `Private colLabels As Collection` at the top of the module, but below the `Option Explicit` line?

Comment: yes. You can look into the file from this link - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tes37auuuidu6p878uydy/PROJECT-BANGLA-KEYBOARD.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=lk56qqg3luhk6mhbcm2rqrcpo)

Comment: Sorry, can't access drop-box here.  Double & triple check your spelling - if you've got `Private colLabels As Collection` and `Set colLabels = New Collection` it should work.  Failing that try `Private colLabels As New Collection` and remove the `Set colLabels = New Collection` line.

Comment: Yep, can't access google drive either.  All locked down here - even if I download it to my phone and email it from there it doesn't get through.

Comment: Where the place are you stuck brother?

Comment: How can I show you. I copied your code in mine. But don't working. Kindly help!

Comment: You could wait 8 hours until I finish here and can try at home. :)

Comment: Ok bro. Waiting for your support!

Comment: waiting for your help bro.